# Get attribute from xml with MySQL

Tags: mysql, xml

I have this xml in a field in MySQL and I want to get just a attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cf:Tag1 Version="3.3" at01="1" at02="2">
    <cf:Tag2 a="A" b="B" c="C"/>
</cf:Tag1>
```

This is the xml file I´m using and this is the query I´ve been using.

```
SELECT ExtractValue(a.xml, '/Version') as ver1
    , ExtractValue(a.xml, '//Version') as ver2
    , ExtractValue(a.xml, 'cf:Tag1[@Version=0]') as ver3
    , ExtractValue(a.xml, 'Tag1[@Version=0]') as ver4
    , ExtractValue(a.xml, 'Tag1[@Version]') as ver5
    , ExtractValue(a.xml, 'cf:Tag1[@Version]') AS ver6
    , ExtractValue(a.xml, '//cf:Tag1[@Version]') AS ver7
    , ExtractValue(a.xml, '//cf:Tag1') AS ver8
FROM table1 a;
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: And what is the question? What is the output you currently get with your query?

Comment: I´m getting empty values or nulls